# Как добавить новую запись в БД через объект?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день, есть таблица в базе данных, этой таблице соответствует класс в модели со следующими полями:

```
 public class price
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_complectation { get; set; }
    public int id_transmission { get; set; }
    public int id_drive { get; set; }
    public int id_model { get; set; }
    public int total_price { get; set; }
}
```

В представлении, используются select'ы для отображения данных, каждой таблицы связанной с таблицей Price. Пример селекта для таблиц Model:

```
<select>
   @foreach (MyCourseProject.Models.model i in ViewBag.mdl)
   {
       <option value="@i.id">@i.name_model</option>
   }
 </select>
```

Вопрос, как выбрав значения во всех селектах, по нажатию кнопки отправить данные в метод "Create" контроллера "First". Пример этого метода:

```
   public ActionResult Create(price PRice)
   {
      db.Price.Add(PRice);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
```

Comment: очень непонятно задан вопрос

Comment: Исправил. Посмотрите.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно так добавляю

```
public ActionResult Create(Price price)
{
    db.Prices.Add(price);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // ...
}
```

Правда в моём коде нет такого что бы прямо сразу объект для базы данных создавался в параметрах функции, я обычно его собираю через ViewModel

```
public ActionResult Create(PriceViewModel priceViewModel)
{
    Price price = new Price();
    price.field1 = priceViewModel.field1;
    price.field2 = priceViewModel.field2;
    // ...

    db.Prices.Add(price);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // ...
}
```

где `db.Prices` это соответствующий `DbSet` в `DbContext`.

Вместо задания прямо в действии контроллера всех полей по отдельности можно использовать функцию, например `Price price = Price.From(priceViewModel);`, в этом случае функцию From надо будет реализовать самому.

Чем второй пример лучше, что в коде функции мы можем программно настроить любую логику создания объекта для создания + валидация.